# Logging inputs on s3 hosted HTML form

Tags: html, logging, amazon-s3

All-

I have set up a simple html form that is hosted on s3. Inputs are queried against a Dynamo database using some underlying java. s3 logs IPs that access the form, but not the inputs themselves. Below is the html that receives the input, what can I add to additionally log what is entered into this form?

```
 <form name="searchForm" ng-submit="formCtrl.sendReq(request)">
          <input type="text" placeholder="ex: acme.com" ng-model="request" autofocus required/>
```

Comment: Please add your code!

Comment: Oops! See edit.

Comment: S3 isn't going to process this form.  It's retrieved for viewing from S3, but it's obviously going to be submitted to some other service, because S3 doesn't process dynamic requests.  Whatever that other service is... that's what you need to be asking about.